# Include folder name in renaming a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, renaming

I've already used that command to rename the files in multiple directories and change JPG to jpg, so I have consistency.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.JPG}$.jpg"' {} \;
```

Do you have any idea how to change that to include the folder name in the name of the file

I am executing that in a folder that contains about 2000 folders (SKU's) or products ... and inside every SKU folder, there are 9 images. 1.jpg 2.jpg .... 9.jpg.

So the bottom-line is I have 2000 images with name 1.jpg, 2.jpg ... 9.jpg. I need those files to be unique, for example:

`folder-name-1.jpg ... folder-name.2.jpg` ... so on, in every folder.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Renaming `1.jpg` to `folder-name-1.jpg` doesn't make it __unique__.  You are essentially trying to add a _prefix_ to all filenames.

Comment: If you would have created the command yourself it would be easy.. Stop using snippets from the net. That's dangerous

Comment: `rename` from Perl distribution might help.

Comment: devnull - the folder name is actually the SKU of the product, so it will be unique.
hek2mgl - I am a php developer, linux is not my strength and I tested the script locally before doing it on the server.

Comment: @pzd060 That is precisely what I said: Prefixing filenames with a given string wouldn't make those unique.

Comment: @devnull Yes, but that string should be known (I cannot use random string), because then I have to use it to import those images in Magento, through Excel. So I should be able to map the files ... to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For example I can do as follows:

```
$ find . -iname '*.jpg' | while read fn; do name=$(basename "$fn") ; dir=$(dirname "$fn") ; mv "$fn" "$dir/$(basename "$dir")-$name" ;done
./lib/bukovina/version.jpg ./lib/bukovina/bukovina-version.jpg
./lib/bukovina.jpg ./lib/lib-bukovina.jpg
```

Comment: To test it I tried  `find ../D44203 -iname '2.jpg' | while read fn; do name=$(basename "$fn") ; dir=$(dirname "$fn") ; mv "$fn" "$dir/$(basename $(pwd))-$name" ;done` and I got ALL?A1?PICS?D44203-2.jpg ... which is not correct, it should be D44203-2.jpg

Comment: @pzd060 `ALL?A1?PICS?D44203-2.jpg ... which is not correct, it should be D44203-2.jpg` should be what? I didn't understand. You don't need a folder before file?

Comment: I wanted to test with ../D44203 ... so only 1 file is affected before running ` find . -iname'*.jpg' `because that will rename 20 000 files and I want to be sure it works.

Comment: @pzd060 replace `mv` with `echo` and show a part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder name of a file you can do `$(basename $(dirname ${FILE}))`, where `${FILE}` is a path that may be relative but must contain at least one folder before the file name in it. This should not be a problem with `find`. If it is, just run it from one directory up.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(basename $(dirname $0))-${0%.JPG}$.jpg"' {} \;
```

Or, if you have JPEGs in your current directory:

```
find ../<dirname> -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(basename $(dirname $0))-${0%.JPG}$.jpg"' {} \;
```

Comment: I am trying it in the current directory (testing purposes) and when I run it, I have
mv: rename ../D44203/9.jpg to D44203/../D44203/9.jpg$.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: @pzd060. Sorry, did not follow my own advice. I just changed the slashes to dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fine one-liner:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir \
      bash -c 'd="${PWD##*/}"; [[ "$1" != "$d-"* ]] && mv "$1" "./$d-$1"' - '{}' \;
```

This command uses safe approach to check whether image name is already not prefixed by the current directory name. You can run it multiple times also and image name won't be renamed after first run.

Comment: On my local computer it worked perfect ... but when I try it on the server I get mv: cannot move `./8.jpg' to ./D46107-./8.jpg': No such file or directory`, do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure you used `-execdir` not `-exec`?

Comment: Of course I am sure, I copy/pasted the same command that worked on my local computer. Strangely on the server it is giving the result I shown you above.

Comment: That's strange since I have tested it again. You can also try: `find . -name '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'd="${1%/*}"; mv "$1" "$d/$d-${1##*/}"' - '{}' \;` command